# In python 3, how can I put individual bytes from a bytes object into a list without them being converted to integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3, I have a `bytes` object that has length greater than 1. I would like to put the individual bytes into a `list` Here is an example:

```
myBytes = b'abc123'  # should turn into [b'a', b'b', b'c', b'1', b'2', b'3']
```

I have tried the following:

```
badList0 = []
badList0.extend(myBytes)  # badList0 = [97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51]

badList1 = []
badList1.extend(bytearray(myBytes))  # badList1 = [97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51]

badList2 = list(myBytes)  # badList2 = [97, 98, 99, 49, 50, 51]

badList3 = [bytes(b) for b in myBytes]  # result is 6 entries with 97, 98, 99, 49, 50, and 51 '\x00's, respectively
```

Is there a clear and efficient way to get the desired result of a list of individual `bytes` objects (`[b'a', b'b', b'c', b'1', b'2', b'3']`) instead of a list of integer values representing those bytes?

Comment: would the `bytearray` type work for you?  It is a built-in different to a `list` but it is a sequence docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range)

Comment: If you only need the `list` for mutability, `bytearray` should work for you. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects

Comment: @iz_ and @Simon Crane, Thank you. I think the ```bytearray``` object actually WILL work for me and maybe be a bit cleaner than what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the ugly way:

```
[bytes([c]) for c in bs]
```

Not sure if there's something much prettier.

Comment: Seems like there could be something more elegant on python 3.9 [PEP 467](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0467/), using `iterbytes `

Answer (score 2):

Decode to `utf-8` and encode back to a bytearray:

```
list(map(str.encode, myBytes.decode("utf-8")))
# [b'a', b'b', b'c', b'1', b'2', b'3']
```

Answer (score 1):

I used: 
`[bytes([myBytes[i]]) for i in range(len(myBytes))]`

And got the output: 
`[b'a', b'b', b'c', b'1', b'2', b'3']`

Comment: FYI, `for i in range(len(myBytes))` is typically an anti-pattern. See juanpa.arrivillaga's answer for a better way of iterating.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
[bytes(i, 'utf-8') for i in myBytes.decode('utf-8')]

# [b'a', b'b', b'c', b'1', b'2', b'3']
```